# proxy to SSL third party site and masquerade url

Tags: ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy

To improve search engine optimization I need to have my SSL-enabled site https://www.company.com/support proxy to our SSL enabled third party support site https://company.custhelp.com, while at the same time making it so the user only sees the former url (www.company.com/support) in their browser. Since this is a support site certain aspects of the URI (session ID) as well as cookies need to be maintained.

What's the best way or application needed to achieve this goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nginx reverse proxying to third party site](http://serverfault.com/questions/509721/nginx-reverse-proxying-to-third-party-site)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Instead, edit your original question to improve it.

Comment: Sorry...I've deleted the previous post since I'm not entirely convinced nginx is the best solution to this problem, and I'm more curious as to what solution in general people might recommend since I'm new to web development and administration.